# how to check menu item existence

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I want to create some menu, example File -> New ,Edit-> Save ,File -> Open ,File -> Save ,File -> Exit

I want to create menu items inside For circle and everytime to check 
if File exist or not and if exist put some item in File submenu

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        action = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        action.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        action.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does "For cicle" mean?

Comment: Sorry i mean circle iteration inside for operator

Comment: I think you mean "for-loop". So what you is want is like a "recent files" submenu?

Comment: fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File') first time I create menu item File and then I create subemenu item fileMenu.addAction(Action1) and then maybe I want to create Action2 but before that I need to know is File parent menu exist or not

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is set the menus as attributes: i.e. `self.fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')`.

Comment: Ah thanks I will try to use hasattr() function

Comment: Okay - but why would you need to check? You know it must be there, because you created it in `initUI`.

Comment: I was write the programm where user can create own options I write one option and user can write some code can notice some information and all this will write as a dictionary  and from there in second programm running new options will added in menu and toolbar

Comment: And every time I need to automaticaly check is user added new menu item example File Edit Help and etc.